# Best practices while calling a Stored Procedure from JDBC

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to improving my application's performance be combining multiple query calls into Stored Procedures. This will reduce n/w traffic, round trips and also separate data-processing logic from application.

While I am at it, I am thinking of using most efficient way to do it.

As of now, I am planning to use `PreparedStatement` with `prepareCall` method.

If there is a better way of doing it, please suggest.

I will need to pass many `IN params` to procedures and will also need `OUT params` back in `JAVA`  code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no "better" way. You are already doing what is better in your application overall. Using Stored Procs, instead of plain SQL. So you got the curve. If you are truly pressed for performance, then you might also want to to take a look at the database itself. Caching, Index, etc. From application, you can employ memcache, a cache layer. But these are not what you are looking for now, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

While your question can be answered quite easily by guiding you towards some tutorials, e.g. from:

- [JDBC and stored procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html)
- [jOOQ and stored procedures](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/stored-procedures/)
- [Spring and stored procedures](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

... I would still like to point out that there are a great number of caveats to using stored procedures in MySQL. Please consider [Bill Karwin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) answer to this Quora question:

- http://www.quora.com/MySQL/What-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-or-not-use-stored-procedures

For instance, the first issue:

> MySQL stored procedures are compiled the first time a session uses them - but the compiled version is discarded at the end of the session. Unlike stored procedures in Oracle or other RDBMS brands, which keep the compiled version persistently. This means that MySQL adds a lot of overhead to procedures, especially if your pattern is to call a procedure only once per session.